# Há algum método LINQ que retorne um valor default de minha preferência?

Tags: c#, linq

Há algum método LINQ que retorne um valor default de minha preferência, que cumpra o papel deste método de uma forma mais eficiente?

```
public static int? procurarIdPorCpf(string cpf)
{
    using (Contexto context = new Contexto())
    {
        if (context.pessoaFisica.Any(p => p.CPF.Equals(cpf)))
            return context.pessoaFisica.First(p => p.CPF.Equals(cpf)).ID;
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: O que seria "mais eficiente", a seu ver? Uma sintaxe mais sucinta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>Use o operador de coalescência nula:</s>

```
return context.pessoaFisica.FirstOrDefault(p => p.CPF.Equals(cpf)) ?? meuValorDefault;
```

Como você indicou que quer o Id, poderia fazer assim:

```
return context.pessoaFisica
              .Where(p => p.CPF.Equals(cpf))
              .Select(p => (int?)p.Id)
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

Neste caso não é necessário o operador `??`, pois o valor de FirstOrDefault já vai sair nulo se não tiver nenhum registro.

Comment: Tu pode adicionar uma breve explicação a respeito deste operador?

Comment: No teste que fiz houve um erro dizendo que tal operador não pode ser usando entre um tipo int e um null.

Comment: Fiz uma pesquisa rapida sobre o operador. Pelo que vi, ele retorna o valor do lado direito caso o valor do lado esquerdo seja nulo. Se for isso mesmo, não se encaixa em tal situação... Meu ID é um int não nulo.

Comment: No caso o tipo tem que ser nullable para funcionar: uma classe ou um tipo tal como `int?`.

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: O segundo exemplo funcinou corretamente, obrigado

Comment: Ganhei um down-vote gratuito?

Comment: Talvez pela falta de observação do primeiro exemplo, porque ele me retorna uma pessoa fisica e não um inteiro.

Comment: Testei o meu método e o das duas respostas no https://dotnetfiddle.net/ e o dessa resposta foi de longe mais rápido.

Answer (score 1):

É melhor percorrer a enumeração apenas uma vez:

```
    public static int? procurarIdPorCpf(string cpf)
    {
        using (Contexto context = new Contexto())
        {
            var pessoa = context.pessoaFisica.FirstOrDefault(p => p.CPF.Equals(cpf));
            return pessoa == null ? null : pessoa.ID;
        }
    }
```

Comment: É que eu não queria selecionar a pessoa em sí, apenas uma de suas propriedades, achei que da forma que fiz seria melhor, pois o faço com milhares de registros e não queria instanciar milhares de objetos pessoa. Mas aproveito para perguntar e tirar uma dúvida, da forma que eu fiz, fica em cache apenas o ID ou o objeto pessoa?